# Analytic functions with integer coefficients

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I would like to ask the following question. This is related to one lemma that I need in a recent research on the arithmetic behavior of transcendental functions with integer coefficients.

*Let $\alpha, \beta\in (-1,1)$, with $\alpha\neq \pm \beta$. I would like to prove that there exists a function $f\in \mathbb{Z}[[z]]$ analytic in the unit ball and such that $f(\beta)=0$ and $f(\alpha)\neq 0$.*

I am able to prove this when $\alpha\cdot \beta<0$ and when $|\beta|>|\alpha|$.

Any help?

Comment: How did you prove it for the cases you mentioned?

Comment: the proof is not that easy, but not too deep. However it is a little hard to explain here. Let me see if someone has a better idea to solve that case $|\alpha|>|\beta|$ or the general case.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: it could be, but it appears in order to prove one lemma in one of my recent works.

Comment: I find this answer on the evasive side. And this just smells like homework to me.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas if a poster asks a question in the form  "*Prove that...*" it does not necessarily mean it is homework... In any case one should not feel offended by the imperative form if it is in italic :)

Comment: @PietroMajer When an anonymous asks to prove a homework-level "lemma", the burden is not us to prove that it is a student trying to have their homeworks solved.

Comment: @BorisBukh Of course the burden is not to us. On the other hand, if we raise a mistrust of somebody's purposes, it is generally acknowledged that we should at least provide a more solid reason than just smell. That's why (IMHO) it is better to stay on the question, objecting either its content or form, not the questioner's good faith. If a question appears too elementary to me, I kindly suggest a more suitable site. But note, what is trivial to you may be difficult to other professional mathematicians, just because it is not their field, and this is a situation where MO proves greatly useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We may assume w.l.o.g $0<\beta<1$. Write $\beta^{-1}$ in the [$ \beta^{-2}$ expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation) as:
$$\beta^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty d_k\beta^{2k}$$
with integer digits $0\le d_k<\beta^{-2}$, and define
$$f(x):=-1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty d_kx^{2k+1}$$
Then $f\in\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ is analytic in the unit disk, strictly increasing on the interval $(-1,1)$, and $f(\beta)=0$.

Comment: @Diego $f$ is strictly increasing, so it has only one zero.

Comment: Thanks @Pietro, it works. Another question, how to manage when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers inside the unit ball with $\alpha$ different of $\beta$ and $\overline{\beta}$?

Comment: Good question! Making $f\in\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ an univalent (slicht) map on the unit disk seems hard to me (but it should be known, and it is worth posting a new question). The sufficient condition on coefficients for univalence I know is Alexander's one: $n|a_n|$ *be decreasing*, but for $f\in\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ it implies $f$ is a polynomial.  On the other hand, de Branges' necessary condition $|a_n|\le n|a_1|$ leaves some hope. If univalence proves hard or impossible, one should try to build an $f$ depending on both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, not only on $\beta$, possibly not slicht.

Comment: Thanks @PietroMajer. I already posed the other question. I think the better idea is to consider a construction depending on both, but I am afraid that I need to split such a construction in many cases depend on the their arguments (rational, irrational, linearly independent, etc).

Comment: If you are ok with $f$ depending on both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then I think the above construction can be repeated. "Complex base system" can be considered like in the real case. I think, given a base $\beta$, a large enough set of coefficients $C$ allows to represent any complex number, so you can make plenty of $f\in\mathbb{Z}[[z]]$ with bounded coefficients such that $f(\beta)=0$; then also getting $f(\alpha)\neq0$ should not be difficult.

Comment: @PietroMajer thanks again. Actually as pointed out in other MO question, it is possible to deduce this by a result of Harbater. However, your idea is related to other problem that I have. Please see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255152/prescribed-analytic-functions-with-integer-coefficients-for-given-values